# MySQL: price changed within last 7 days

Tags: mysql

I have the following data (products with its prices and dates of price):

```
prodId priceDate  price 
======+==========+=====
    1 |2017-11-24|  600 
    1 |2017-11-21|  600 
    1 |2017-11-18|  600 
    1 |2017-11-15|  500 
    1 |2017-11-05|  400 
    1 |2017-11-03|  400 
    2 |2017-11-11|  300
```

I need an indicator (column chg) which will show if product price had been changed within previous 7 days.

```
prodId priceDate  price chg
======+==========+=====+===
    1 |2017-11-24|  600| N  
    1 |2017-11-21|  600| Y  
    1 |2017-11-18|  600| Y  
    1 |2017-11-15|  500| N  
    1 |2017-11-05|  400| N  
    1 |2017-11-03|  400| N  
    2 |2017-11-14|  300| N
```

How this SQL query should look like?

Comment: 2.5k rep with a question like this?

Comment: @sentinel I tried so far this: `select prodId,preisDatum,preis,
(select preis from preise p2 where p2.prodId=p.prodId and p2.preisDatum<p.preisDatum order by preisDatum desc limit 1)
from preise p` but this query shows last previous price - not if there was change within 7 days.

Comment: @davidbuzatto, ok maybe I'm just tired from job today and cannot see the simplicity of this solution or you don't see complexity of question, so please help and offer the solution

Comment: So @Sentinel just biting comment, no contribution.

Comment: @sbrbot by the time I got back to you, two other users had provided answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I found the solution myself (checking if there is at least 1 `COUNT()>0` price different than current one `p2.price!=p.price` within previous 7 days `p2.priceDate BETWEEN p.priceDate - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND p.priceDate` for that particular product `p2.prodId=p.prodId`):

```
SELECT prodId,priceDate,price,
IF((SELECT COUNT(p2.price)
      FROM prices AS p2 
     WHERE p2.prodId=p.prodId AND p2.price!=p.price
       AND p2.priceDate BETWEEN p.priceDate - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND p.priceDate),'Y','N') AS chg
FROM prices p
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a035/23)

Answer (score 1):

This is not tested, but may give you an idea. Join to all rows for the product in the last 7 days. Count the distinct prices. If the count is 1, then the price has not changed.

```
SELECT p1.prodId, p1.priceDate, MAX(p1.price) AS price,
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT p2.price) WHEN 1 THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS chg
FROM MyTable AS p1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS p2 
 ON p1.prodId = p2.prodId 
 AND p2.priceDate BETWEEN p1.priceDate - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND p1.priceDate
GROUP BY p1.prodId, p1.priceDate
```